# how to access the dom of a popup in IE8

Tags: javascript, dom

Once you open a window using window.open, how do you access the dom of the popup

Comment: Have your doubt been cleared? If so, please, consider coming back to mark an answer as correct or post your solution.

Answer (score 3):

window.open returns you a window object. That window object's document property would return the DOM of the elements in the window.

```
var win = window.open("../test.html");
win.document.forms[0];
```